# Trying to find the percent change within a group between specific rows R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, difference

I have a snippet of my dataframe as follows

```
x = data.frame(retailer = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
store = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), 
month = c(2110, 2109, 2108, 2107, 2106, 2105, 2104, 2103, 2102, 2101, 2012, 2011,
  2010, 2009, 2008, 2007),
dollars = c(121817.9, 367566.7, 507674.5, 421257.8, 453330.3, 607551.4, 462674.8,
  464329.1, 339342.3, 549271.5, 496720.1, 554858.7, 382675.5,
  373210.9, 422534.2, 381668.6))
```

where for the month variable 2110 corresponds to the month of October in the year 2021 and 2010 would be October in the year 2020, 2109 is September 2021 etc. I am trying to find the percent difference in dollars between the most recent month and the same month from only one year prior through the grouping of retailer and store.

I thought I would be able to index into the rows within each group and do the percent change between the 13th row and the first row of each store group as this would give the current month and that same month from a year ago.

So far I have:

```
data = x %>%
  group_by(retailer, store)
```

but I am not sure how to incorporate calculating the percent change within this.

Comment: In the exxample, retailer 2 store 5 have only year 2021 values.  So what will be the difference

Comment: You only provide 8 months of data in your example for each store, so for the example data all the values would be `NA`. That said, I think you're looking for something like this `x %>%  group_by(retailer, store) %>% arrange(desc(month)) %>% mutate(pct_change = dollars/lead(dollars, 12) -1)`

Comment: My apologies, just updated my data!

Comment: If I had wanted to do the second month per group and find the percent difference of that month from a year ago (say 2109 and 2009) would I have to do -2 instead of -1 in the last mutate function? I am not sure what the -1 is currently doing

Comment: The formula for percent change is `(Current Value/Prior Value) - 1`, so the -1 doesn't change. `lead(dollars, 12)` is the value of dollars from 12 periods earlier, i.e. 1 year ago.

Comment: @JaneMiller do you need `x %>% mutate(Date = as.Date(str_c(month, '01'), '%y%m%d'), year = year(Date), month2 = month(Date)) %>% arrange(retailer, store, desc(year), desc(month2)) %>% group_by(retailer, store, month2) %>% mutate(pct_change =  dollars/lead(dollars)) %>% ungroup`